# what is the most efficient way of looping through a list in Redis

Tags: php, redis, feed

I am trying to create an activity feed for each user in my application. I want to use Redis to store two lists per user. One for storing the ids of user's followers and one for storing the ids of the activities from every user he/she is following.

So what I want to do is when a user adds a post/creates an activity I want to push the id of that post/created activity to the list of every user whose id is in the user's followers list.

I am assuming I would have to loop through the 'followers list' to this, but I have no idea how to accomplish this in Redis.

I am using PHP as my server side language but I don't think it would make sense to do it there or is it ok to do that way? 
I believe Redis has a much more efficient and faster way of doing this, especially if the 'followers list' contains 1000000s of records.

E.g

```
 // to add followers to user with id of 1
 lpush user.1.followers 4 90 3 48 8 2 45

 // to get all user with id 1 followers    
 lrange user.1.followers 0 -1
```

Comment: You could do this in redis (by writing a custom lua function), but I think it's far better to do it from the application. Yes, you'll lose some time on network roundtrips, but redis will be much more responsive. As a good middle ground, update in redis (the abovementioned lua function), but in small batches of users (say, 50-100 users per batch, not all 10 million at once)

Comment: thank you very much !! i just read on how i run a lua script using the eval command....but how can i execute it in batches ?

Comment: Get total number of user's followers (say, it's 10k), then issue a series of lua function invocations, "update users from place 0 in the followers list to place 49th", "update users from place 50 to place 99" and so on, until you reach the length of the list

Comment: Lists do not seem to be the best data structure here - accessing anything but their ends is an expensive operation. Sorted Sets would be better here - the can be paged by rank/score. Look up Redis and Twitter on Google for inspiration ;)